# How is an extreme insulin overdose counteracted

Tags: endocrinology, diabetes-mellitus, insulin

I just watched this comedy skit that went -

Trainee: I just gave him 10 of insulin

Doctor: 10 what?

Trainee: 10cc

Doctor: * look of terror *

As a diabetic myself I know that 10cc or 1000u is an insane amount of insulin to have in one go. A 10ml vial (1000u) would usually last me over 2 weeks.

1000u in one go would most certainly be fata (if untreated) whether the patient was diabetic or not. Although individual insulin sensitivity varies greatly, I, personally, know that I would need around 1500g of sugar/glucose to counter that much insulin which I would've thought just isn't possible. What I'm wondering is, is there some other way that, assuming you're already in a hospital, they could counteract, filter out, or otherwise manage such a severe overdose? Or is IV glucose the only option?

I know glucagon injections can be use to treat severe hypoglycaemia but from my research the average person would no have enough stored glycogen. Please tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're worried about. The doctor is right there. I assume the trainee didn't give 10cc sq (that's a big bolus, and certainly too big for an sq dose.) So one can assume it was given IV. **IV insulin only lasts a few minutes.** A liter of D5&W (1000 x.05 =50g glucose) wide open and the crisis is averted. It's not momentary hypoglycemia that causes the worst outcomes; it's *prolonged* hypoglycemia. (I know a resident who mistakenly ordered IV instead of sq insulin. Nothing happened.) It is used, though, to treat DKA.

Comment: SQ insulin lasts for hours, a few to a lot depending on the type. A hefty dose of sq insulin without po intake can be, and has been, lethal.

Comment: @anongoodnurse so what youre saying is IV insulin is metabolised very quickly and even an large dose would be easily fixed?

Comment: Say someone did manage a 10cc sq overdose. How would you manage that?

Comment: See long explanation above. Just a lot longer observation period.